# Populating global list without use of ng2 services

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm making an app that will be loading several different components using DynamicComponentLoader.

Previously, I was using a service to create a global list of components:

```
export class MyService {
  list = [];

  get(): string[] {
    return this.list;
  }

  add(value: string): void {
    this.list.push(value);
  }
}
```

Inside each component in my app, I would use MyService.add('component_name') to populate my list. This works fine for components which are loaded upon init.

Any components loaded dynamically, however, will not populate the list in my service until the component is loaded. As a result, my global list of components is incomplete when the app is first loaded.

Is there an alternative method to services which can be used to create a global list of components? A TypeScript global var, perhaps? I just want one big list when my root component is first loaded.

Comment: I dont get your problem exactly but i think 'eventemitter' can be a way ...

Comment: Sounds like you want to get a list of all components defined in your application (or imported somewhere). I don't know if reflection in TypeScript allows you to get all reachable classes that have a `@Component()` decorator (I'm using Dart and have only limited TS knowledge). You could maintain the list of dynamically loaded components  manually ;-) `list = [DynamicC1, DynamicC2, ...]`

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Yeah, this is exactly what I'm trying to do (find a way to get a list of any class which have the `@Component` decorator). Currently I'm manually populating a list, seems to be the best solution for now. I'm hoping to find a more dynamic way to detect these components.

Comment: @micronyks I had tried eventemitter when I set up my initial service, this works fine for components that are loaded with the app. The problem here is any component loaded dynamically will not fire the event until it is loaded, so the initial list I have when the root component is first initialized is incomplete.